# Getting error: Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient.set_BaseUrl(System.String)'

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

Im trying to send an email from my app using Restsharp. This was not written by me but I was given to resolve the error. This is my SendMessage.cs method.

```
public static string SendMessage(EmailModel emailModel)
{
    try
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/xyz.lk");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MailGunAPIKey"));
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        request.AddParameter("domain", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("domain"), ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
        request.AddParameter("from", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("fromEmail"));
        //request.AddParameter("to", "xxx@yyy.com");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> emailItem in emailModel.toEmailList)
        {
            request.AddParameter("to", emailItem.Value);
        }
        request.AddParameter("bcc", "ask@xxx.lk");
        request.AddParameter("subject", emailModel.subject);
        request.AddParameter("html", emailModel.emailBody);

        if (emailModel.Path != null)
        {
            request.AddFile("attachment", Path.Combine(emailModel.Path));
        }                

        request.Method = Method.POST;
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        return response.Content;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Elmah.ApplicationException("Failed to send email message.",ex);
    }
}
```

When i try to call this function from EmailUtility.cs, I  get the error. This is EmailUtility.cs

```
public bool SendEmailFromAPI(EmailType template, Order order, string subject, string path)
{  
    if (order != null )
    {
        if (template != EmailType.RedeemActivationCode)
        {
            string[] toEmails = { order.SenderEmail };
            EmailModel emailContentModel = new EmailModel { toEmails = toEmails, mapId = order.ID, emailBody = GetEmailBody(template, order), subject = subject, Path = path };

            emailContentModel.toEmailList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(order.SenderName, order.SenderEmail));
            string response = "";
            if (path.Length > 0)
                response = EmailManager.SendMessage(emailContentModel);
            else
                response = EmailManager.SendMessageWithoutAttachment(emailContentModel);
        }
        else
        {
            string[] toEmails = { order.SenderEmail };
            EmailModel emailContentModel = new EmailModel { toEmails = toEmails, mapId = order.ID, emailBody = "Your PIN number is " + order.ActivateCode, subject = subject, Path = null };

            emailContentModel.toEmailList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(order.SenderName, order.SenderEmail));
            string response = EmailManager.SendMessage(emailContentModel);                    
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When executing the following part of the emailUtility.cs,

```
response = EmailManager.SendMessage(emailContentModel);
```

I get the error

```
Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient.set_BaseUrl(System.Uri)'.
```

Comment: What is the RestSharp version? There were a lot of posts about this problem.

Comment: 104.4.. Couldnt find exactly my problem